# New create-react-app failing to compile sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I've had issues with my react project and as such i've just made a new reactapp and updated all the packages in my package.json. However, Either the updated react version, react dependancies or node-sass is not allowing the project to be compiled. It installs without any vulnerabilities which is great, but the sass compiler doesn't want to play ball.

Folder structures as follows

```
--src
  --api
  --assets
    --fonts
    --images
  --components
  --pages
  --scss
    --_variables.scss
    --_media.scss
    --_mavigation.scss
  --App.scss
  --App.js
  --index.js
```

seems to break whenever i'm referring to background-images in css, i can't seem to get the right path to work, despite the same paths working in an older version of reactjs.

I get the following error

```
Failed to compile.

    ./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/App.scss)
    Module not found: Can't resolve './scss/assets/images/camera.png' in 'xxxproject/src'
```

The css this is erroring on is as follows;

```
background-image: url('./assets/images/camera.png');
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: are you having your camera.png image in images folder or not ??

Comment: Yes, file is definitely there, you can see in the error msg though it's trying to find the assets older within the scss folder 'Can't resolve './scss/assets/images/camera.png''

Comment: are you using wabpack configuration ???

Comment: no i'm not using webpack specifically (although i think create-react-app used webpack as a dependancy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is like

Background url is like

```
'./assets/images/camera.png'
```

Node sass tring to resolve it at

```
'./scss/assets/images/camera.png'' ///scss causing problem
```

Solution : use ../ in background-image

```
 background-image: url('../assets/images/camera.png'); // as per your folder structur
```

Comment: Thanks mate - i don't know why this relative path would of changed from one version of react to the next, but its all working now

Comment: Would i be better using webpack - i'm not to savvy on it, from what i can gather it's used more for projects using nodejs, which this isn't?